# Excel formula to return value based on header and two columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, comparison

I'm trying to write an Excel formula that will place an "X" in a cell if the value in the header row occurs anywhere in column A while the values in Column B are unchanged. I envision the result looking like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use COUTNIFS:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A:$A,C$1,$B:$B,$B2),"X","")
```

It will count if the header if found in A where B matches what is in B2.  If it returns anything but `0` it will return `X` otherwise an empty string.

[image]